# Destructure an Object Like An Array in JS?

Tags: javascript

Given the following code:

```
const civic = {make: 'Honda', model: 'Civic'};

function logArgs(make, model) {
  console.log(make);
  console.log(model)
}
```

I want to do this:

```
logArgs(...civic);
```

instead of:

```
logArgs(civic.make, civic.model);
```

I get:

> (index):39 Uncaught TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator

Is there some way to destructure objects like arrays, or is what I am trying to do impossible?

Comment: it is unclear which function do you like to use after spreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
logArgs(...Object.values(civic))
```

Note that this would rely on the order of objects, which can be tricky

Comment: This is the solution I ended up using, thank you. Nina has an interesting approach too.

Answer (score 4):

Use [destructuring in arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter)

```js
const civic = {make: 'Honda', model: 'Civic'};

function logArgs({make, model}) {
  console.log(make);
  console.log(model)
}

logArgs(civic)
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, but it's correct and I'm not sure the question is actually answerable...so have a +1!

Comment: This only works for the given object, doesn't the OP want a generic version for any object?

Answer (score 1):

For spreading, you need to implement a [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) for the object, because objects do not have a built in iterator.

This approach takes the values only, but any other approach may work, like to return the entries.

```js
function logArgs([make, model]) {
  console.log(make);
  console.log(model)
}

const civic = { make: 'Honda', model: 'Civic' };

civic[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    yield Object.values(civic);
};

logArgs(...civic);
```

Comment: Not fully following on how this is different from Juan's answer.

Comment: Had to look this up as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

Ty again for interesting answer.

Answer (score 0):

In destructuring the object parameter civic, we get a more concise function, Or you can just destructure `civic` to assign diffrent variables as shown below

```js
const civic = {make: 'Honda', model: 'Civic'};
const { make, model, year = "2019" } = civic; 
 console.log(make);
  console.log(year);

function logArgs({make, model}) {
  console.log(make);
  console.log(model)
 
}

logArgs(civic)
```

Comment: I have shown the function parameter destructuring and object destructuring